# GWT Button Click Enable/Disable Pattern -- GwtEvent assertLive() in dev mode

Tags: gwt

To avoid users clicking repetitively on the same button and by the same token send multiple requests to server, I have used the following pattern:

1. In button ClickHandler.onClick, disable the button.
2. In call back, re-enable the button.

See pattern in code below.  The "rpcCall" function below basically is the core implementation of the Button onClick(final ClickEvent event).

```
private void rpcCall(final ClickEvent event)
{
  final AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new AsyncCallback<Void>()
  {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void result)
    {
      final Button source = (Button) event.getSource(); // Dev mode isLive assertion failure.
      source.setEnabled(true);
      // Process success...
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
    {
      final Button source = (Button) event.getSource();
      source.setEnabled(true);
      // Process error...
    }
  };
  // Disable sender.
  final Button source = (Button) event.getSource();
  source.setEnabled(false);
  // RPC call.
  final RpcAsync rpcAsync = getRpcAsync();
  RpcAsync.rpcCall(..., callback);
}
```

I just noticed a "This event has already finished being processed by its original handler manager, so you can no longer access it" exception caused by an isLive assertion failure in dev mode when the onSuccess async function calls event.getSource().

It seems to work in production/javascript mode though.

This dev mode assertion failure makes me question this pattern.

Is it a good pattern?  Why do I get the exception only in dev mode?  What would be a better pattern?

Obviously, I could bypass the call to event.getSource() by passing the source Button as an argument of the rpc wrapper call function, but it seems redundant with the event object already carrying such a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, the way you got the event object in IE was to use `window.event`, which only lasted the time to process the event. GWT's `Event` object therefore had to put guards so you're discouraged to keep a hold on an event instance, as it could suddenly reflect another event being processed, or no event at all (weird!)
Fortunately, Microsoft has since fixed their browser, and this is why it works when you test it (I bet you didn't test in IE6 ;-) ).

The *correct* way to handle that situation is to extract all the data you need from the event and keep them in `final` variables:

```java
private void rpcCall(final ClickEvent event)
{
  final Button source = (Button) event.getSource();

  final AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new AsyncCallback<Void>()
  {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void result)
    {
      source.setEnabled(true);
      // Process success...
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
    {
      source.setEnabled(true);
      // Process error...
    }
  };
  // Disable sender.
  source.setEnabled(false);
  // RPC call.
  final RpcAsync rpcAsync = getRpcAsync();
  RpcAsync.rpcCall(..., callback);
}
```